# Mount combo (USB/COM) device

Tags: macos, usb, external-disk, mount

I've bought [this simple navigator](http://www.o-synce.com/en/products/navigation-gps/navi2move.html) that works fine on PC using the software released by the company but there is no mac version for it. Under mac the navigator [was supposed to be mounted as an external drive](http://help.routeyou.com/topic/view/369/o-synce-navi2move-navi2coach.en). But this doesn't happen.

I've left a question for the company support team, but it seems to be unlikely to get a proper answer. Is there any way to force it to mount as an external drive?

I'm using macbook pro running OS X Yosemite 10.10.2. When I plug in the device on USB, I can see this controller is up 'CP2102 USB to UART Bridge Controller' in the system details, but i have no idea what to do next.

Comment: The second site you link to says `Connect your navi2coach to your computer... On a MAC a new device “navi2coach” will be recognized.` You have a **navi2move**. As these are different products, I assume that your device is simply not supported on the Mac. This is in congruence with the text on the [Functions page](http://www.o-synce.com/en/products/navigation-gps/navi2move.html) of your device, where the only supported OS is Windows.

Comment: Yeah, I was wondering if there is any way to force mount...

Answer (score 1):

Please try install this driver:
https://www.pololu.com/file/download/48014_SiLabsUSBDriverDisk.zip?file_id=0J547

I have a amateur radio which uses a similar driver (CP210x USB to UART Bridge Controller) and I had to install it too...

EDIT:

Actually the driver is the same for CP210x and CP2102...

Comment: If you already installed this driver just tell me...

Comment: No I didn't. So it sounds like I shouldn't should i?

Comment: @MikeK Can you try?

Comment: @MikeK When you install please unplug the device, in my case first time I installed, with device plugged in don't recognized and I had to reinstall... without plugged in...

Comment: what is the difference with the one I already have installed with OS X?